# Find a process corresponding to a covariance function.

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance

Given a stochastic process, I know how to find its covariance function, but is there anything available for the inverse?

For instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_function#Parametric_families_of_covariance_functions lists 2 parametric functions:

$$C(x,y)=\sigma^2 e^{-d(x,y)}$$

and

$$C(x,y)=\sigma^2 e^{-d^2(x,y)}$$

for some distance function $d(x,y)$.

It says as well that the former generates non-smooth paths, and the latter smooth paths.

What processes have such covariance functions? and how can I estimate the implied smoothness of the paths?